# How does wait succeed for a block that is to be executed on the next dispatch?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, xctest

```
import XCTest
@testable import TestWait

class TestWait: XCTestCase {
    
    func testX() {
        guard Thread.isMainThread else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let exp = expectation(description: "x")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("block execution")
            exp.fulfill()
        }
        print("before wait")
        wait(for: [exp], timeout: 2)
        print("after wait")
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
before wait
block execution
after wait
```

I'm trying to rationalize the sequence of the prints. This is what I think:

1. the test is ran on main thread
2. it dispatches a block off the main thread, but since the dispatch happens from the main thread, then the block execution has to wait till the current block is executed
3. "before wait" is printed
4. we `wait` for the expectation to get fulfilled. This wait sleeps the current thread, ie the main thread for 2 seconds.

So how in the world does wait succeed even though we still haven't dispatched off of main thread. I mean "after wait" isn't printed yet! So we must still be on main thread. Hence the "block execution" never has a chance to happen.

What is wrong with my explanation? I'm guessing I it must be something with how `wait` is implemented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wait(for:timeout:)` of `XCTestCase` is not like the GCD group/semaphore `wait` functions with which you are likely acquainted.

When you call [`wait(for:timeout:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/2806856-wait), much like the GCD `wait` calls, it will not return until the timeout expires or the expectations are resolved. But, in the case of `XCTestCase` and unlike the GCD variations, inside `wait(for:timeout:)`, it is looping, repeatedly calling [`run(mode:before:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1411525-run) until the expectations are resolved or it times out. That means that although `testX` will not proceed until the `wait` is satisfied, the calls to `run(mode:before:)` will allow the run loop to continue to process events (including anything dispatched to that queue, including the completion handler closure). Hence no deadlock.

Probably needless to say, this is a feature of `XCTestCase` but is not a pattern to employ in your own code.

Regardless, for more information about how Run Loops work, see the [Threading Programming Guide: Run Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).

Comment: so anytime a thread blocks a queue, there is no such thing like ` run(mode:before:)` happening. However that happens for `wait(for:timeout:)` hence other things dispatched to the queue can get performed?

Comment: When using `wait` on semaphore or dispatch group, correct, that simply blocks the thread from doing _anything_ until the semaphore or group is satisfied. Waiting for expectations, however, spins on the runloop, allowing the runloop to process events.

Comment: So runloops work on top of gcd/queues. Gcd doesn’t work on top of runloops?

Comment: Waiting for expectations spin a runloop on the thread. GCD semaphore/group `wait` simply block the thread.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, look at the source code!

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/blob/ab1677255f187ad6eba20f54fc4cf425ff7399d7/Sources/XCTest/Public/Asynchronous/XCTWaiter.swift#L358

The whole waiting code is not simple but the actual wait boils down to:

```
_ = runLoop.run(mode: .default, before: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: timeIntervalToRun))
```

You shouldn't think about waits in terms of *threads* but in terms of *queues*. By `RunLoop.current.run()` you basically tell the current code to start executing other items in the queue.

Comment: 1. I’m not super familiar with what run does. Can you elaborate a bit or share a simple example of how it works? 2. “You basically tell the current code to start executing other items in the queue”. Is “after wait” considered ‘other items in the queue’? Can you write something like my 4 steps?

Comment: Do you mean it allows other items as in the “block execution” to execute all while its very own block is stopped from further execution? That’s weird but is starting to make sense

Comment: @Honey The main thread looks basically like this (in pseudocode) `while !queue.isEmpty { queue.executeFirstTask() }`. Your code is one of such tasks. To wait, you do `while !queue.isEmpty && Date() < before { queue.executeFirstTask() }`. This is what a `RunLoop` does. A task is represented by a closure. However, the actual connection between a `RunLoop` and queues on the main thread is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The `wait` function utilizes `NSRunLoop` inside most likely. The run loop doesn't block the main thread like `sleep` functions do. Despite execution of the function `testX` does not move on. The run loop still accepts events scheduled at the thread and dispatches them to be executed.

UPDATE:

This is how I envision the work of a run loop. In a pseudocode:

```
while (currentDate < dateToStopRunning && someConditionIsTrue()) 
{
   if (hasEventToDispatch()) //has scheduled block?
   {
        runTheEvent();// yes, we have a block, so we run it! 
   }
}
```

The block that you put for async execution is checked inside `hasEventToDispatch()` method and is executed. It fullfils the expectation which is checked at the next iteration of the `while` loop in `someConditionIsTrue()` so the `while` loop exits. `testX` continues exection and `after wait` is printed

Comment: “The run loop still accepts events scheduled at the thread” so how come “after wait” doesn’t get printed and waits? Perhaps I don’t understand how exactly runloop works. Can you elaborate a bit please

Comment: Updated my answer